# Sign PDF documents digitally with Python

Tags: python, pdf, digital-signature

I am trying to sign PDF documents with Python and found something called [MyPDFSigner](http://www.kryptokoder.com/download.html).

It is well documented, however I found the documentation a bit confusing.
The only problem I am having is on how to install the `mypdfsigner` module to run the code to sign a document.

The documentation itself provided a code sample but while the module isn't installed I won't be able to run it:

```
inputPath = "/tmp/input.pdf"
outputPath = "/tmp/output.pdf"
location = "Chicago, Illinois"
reason = "Demo"
contactInfo = "+1 555-555-5555"
certify = True
visible = True
title = "Signing with MyPDFSigner"
author = "KryptoKoder"
subject = "Python Extension"
keywords = "PKCS#12, PDF, MyPDFSigner"
confFile = ""   # defaults to /usr/local/mypdfsigner/mypdfsigner.conf if empty
timestamp = True

print mypdfsigner.sign(inputPath, outputPath, location, reason, contactInfo, certify, visible, title, author, subject, keywords, confFile, timestamp)
```

Does anyone already tried this tool and have any advice for me? Or if you know any other Python library that signs PDF files please tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.kryptokoder.com/signwithext.html) says:

> In Windows copy the file `mypdfsigner.pyd` from `"C:\Program Files\MyPDFSigner"` to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages.`

It also says you need to add the installation to your path:

> To run the example in Windows add "C:\Program Files\MyPDFSigner" to the environment PATH variable

Additionally, you must configure it first:

> Before using any of the extensions it is necessary to start with the graphical application to create a configuration file for the key store and alias one wants to use. The application creates a .mypdfsigner file in your home directory.

Comment: You are right, thanks. I missed that, my bad. However, after doing that, when running test.py it gives me an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyPDFSigner\tests\test.py", line 3, in <module> import mypdfsigner
ImportError: DLL load failer: Impossible to find the specified module.
Do you think that it has something to do with some DLL?

Comment: Updated with further references to the documentation

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Guess I'll have to pay more attention to the documentation from now on.

Comment: Hi @PeterWood, I want to sign a PDF document with a signed Hash that i receive from user. I tried to find out any such example but lucky find your post. Can you please guide/refer me to implement such requirement.

Comment: @ZeeshanBilal I know nothing about it. I looked up the documentation and helped a stranger. Teach a man to fish...