# How to sign a PDF with a signed hash (preferably Python)

Tags: python, pdf, signing, eid

I want to sign a PDF file with an eID card (essentially a smartcard), preferably in python.

I accomplished to have a signed hash of the file, but I can't find out how to embed this hash with the PDF file; and I presume the certificate will also need to be embedded?

Can you point me to some usable libraries or samples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to digitally sign PDF documents using Python with an etoken (pen drive)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45058556/how-to-digitally-sign-pdf-documents-using-python-with-an-etoken-pen-drive)

Comment: Not really, because in that example they provide the P12 certificate. I don't have those.
I only have a SHA256 hash of the file that has been signed with the smartcard, and the public certificates (without private keys etc).

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629410/sign-pdf-documents-digitally-with-python

Comment: That last one also doesn't apply, because you need to configure the signing information in a config file. However the signer is a visitor of our web application.
Imagine it like this; you get a PDF offer in front of you, using some local eID library you can get a signed hash of the file. I want to send the signed hash back to my server side and add it to the PDF.